# How to Send Messages From Client With Button Without Resetting TCP Client?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

so I have a simple Windows Forms Application, and it is a chat room. Everything is working well so far, the servers are connecting fine, but what I want, is that the client can send a message to the server by pressing the send button. Here is the code for when the send button is pressed:

```
private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
        Stream stream = tcp.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding asii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] by = asii.GetBytes(sendBox.Text);
        messageBox.Text += "\nTransmitting...";
        messageBox.Refresh();
        stream.Write(by, 0, by.Length);
        messageBox.Text += "\nTransmitted!";
        messageBox.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception eg) {
        messageBox.Text += Convert.ToString(eg);
        messageBox.Refresh();
    }

}
```

When I tried to send a message, it gave me an error;

> The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.

I heavily believe that this is because of I had to call `TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();`, since with my limited knowledge, I'd think that would quit the current connection. How can I stay connected like this, but still send messages with a send button?

P.S If you need to see more of my code, like the server or the connection, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

can't see you are connecting your tcp client object anywhere. you need to either pass ip / port in .ctor, either invoke `.Connect(...)` method.

or: if you are going to use that client more intensively you re-use it by making it form's property or a public property of your server/communication class so form can access it.

btw most clean solution (easier to maintain and test) would be to remove that tcp class from form anyway and create a class responsible for communciation only. this class could have a SendMessage method with string argument and handle creating and connecting tcp client and sending the text.

if that is something else: what is the error? (would be good to send the exception's message in question in such cases)

Comment: The problem with connecting again, is it disconnects from the server, meaning that the server is no longer looking for connections.